# Is the key safe if attacker know the encrypted and decrypted message?

Tags: brute-force-attack, aes-gcm

Given an attacker know both the encrypted message (+ an iv) and the equivalent decrypted message, is it possible for him to craft a new encrypted message that could result in a desired decrypted message? I'm using aes-256-gcm algorithm specifically.

Comment: Note that your question (kind of) implies that replay attacks are not feasible. They should however be considered. Other protocol errors could include tricking any party (including a receiving party, if the receiving party can also send, this is symmetric encryption after all) into generating the required packet. That the cipher isn't vulnerable doesn't mean that the protocol is secure, in other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES needs significantly more the 2^100 Pairs of Plaintext/Ciphertext to get the key/forge a message. There is no realistic attack against AES.

Answer (score 3):

For any proper encryption algorithm, it is safe. The type of vulnerability you are describing is a key recovery attack or a forgery attack involving known plaintext-ciphertext pairs. Only very insecure ciphers are vulnerable to that attack, and strong, modern ones like AES are not.

Comment: This is not a key recovery attack, rather a forging attack. Key recovery would enable decryption by the attacker of existing messages. Forging allows the attacker to create new valid messages, but not the ability to decrypt. It is still a serious vulnerability but not necessarily as bad as key recovery (which also enables forging).